# Machine code on user stack - Operating Systems

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, stack, kernel

I am working with the xv6 operating system and my class is working on implementing signals for it.

I have already figured out how to implement handlers within the kernel (those were the first two exercises), but now I have to figure out how to run a user-defined handler.

The program calls a signal function that looks like this

```
signal(int signum, void (*handler)(int))
```

The user program, say alarmtest3.c, passes its user-function as the second argument:

```
signal (14, snooze); // 14 is the signum for alarm
```

What I need to figure out is once in signal, how to get the kernel to call another system call sigret(). I believe this system call is needed to store a copy of the trapframe of the kernel's stack. The point is to go back to user space after everything has occurred.

The user stack should look like this:

```
|other stack frames|
|a few bytes of machine code to call sys_sigret|
|signum parameter for the handler function|
|address of the first byte of the code above|
```

I know what machine code to store, I found it in an assembly file. I just do not know what is meant by "a few bytes of machine code to call sys_sigret". How do I store this machine code on the stack?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing code on the stack is not necessarily a good idea, but if you are required to do that, so be it. As to the how: just create said machine code in your kernel memory then simply copy it to the user stack along with its own address so that it will be executed when the signal handler returns.

This is how linux does it:

```
static const struct {
        u16 poplmovl;
        u32 val;
        u16 int80;
} __attribute__((packed)) retcode = {
        0xb858,         /* popl %eax; movl $..., %eax */
        __NR_sigreturn,
        0x80cd,         /* int $0x80 */
};

/*
 * This is popl %eax ; movl $__NR_sigreturn, %eax ; int $0x80
 *
 * WE DO NOT USE IT ANY MORE! It's only left here for historical
 * reasons and because gdb uses it as a signature to notice
 * signal handler stack frames.
 */
err |= __put_user(*((u64 *)&retcode), (u64 *)frame->retcode);
```

Comment: "just create said machine code in your kernel memory" -- So, if I already have the machine code that needs to be executed (since it is a system call, I found the machine code for sys_sigret() in an .asm file), then I would just initialized the respective areas of the struct to the corresponding pieces of machine code?

Comment: `sys_sigret` is the actual kernel handler for the system call, I assume. **You do not want that**. You want a piece of code that invokes that system call, in whatever way your OS is using. On linux, it was an `int 0x80` call after `eax` has been set to the syscall number.

Comment: I have 8 bytes of machine code, i was thinking, instead of 'u32 val; u16 int80;' (I am not entirely sure what the variables inside of the struct are doing) could I store my machine code into two ints? Also, if sys_sigret calls sigret(), is that necessarily a bad thing. I have to ask because otherwise I wont understand.

Comment: You can store your code however you like. The struct is just so that the actual syscall number is separated to a field of its own. I don't understand your question about `sys_sigret` and `sigret` (I don't even know what sigret in your code is).

Comment: I see. Cool. Oh, about the sys_sigret/sigret -- I need to figure out how to properly implement that. But your answer helped a lot! Thanks!